# Can't rename blob file in Azure Storage

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to rename blob in azure storage via .net API and it is I am unable to rename a blob file after a day : (

Here is how I am doing it, by creating new blob and copy from old one.

```
var newBlob = blobContainer.GetBlobReferenceFromServer(filename);

newBlob.StartCopyFromBlob(blob.Uri);

blob.Delete();
```

There is no new blob on server so I am getting http 404 Not Found exception.

Here is working example that i have found but it is for old .net Storage api.

```
CloudBlob blob = container.GetBlobReference(sourceBlobName);
CloudBlob newBlob = container.GetBlobReference(destBlobName);
newBlob.UploadByteArray(new byte[] { });
newBlob.CopyFromBlob(blob);
blob.Delete();
```

Currently I am using 2.0 API. Where I am I making a mistake?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I see that you're using `GetBlobReferenceFromServer` method to create an instance of new blob object. For this function to work, the blob must be present which will not be the case as you're trying to rename the blob.

What you could do is call `GetBlobReferenceFromServer` on the old blob, get it's type and then either create an instance of BlockBlob or PageBlob and perform copy operation on that. So your code would be something like:

```
    CloudBlobContainer blobContainer = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient().GetContainerReference("container");
    var blob = blobContainer.GetBlobReferenceFromServer("oldblobname");
    ICloudBlob newBlob = null;
    if (blob is CloudBlockBlob)
    {
        newBlob = blobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference("newblobname");
    }
    else
    {
        newBlob = blobContainer.GetPageBlobReference("newblobname");
    }
    //Initiate blob copy
    newBlob.StartCopyFromBlob(blob.Uri);
    //Now wait in the loop for the copy operation to finish
    while (true)
    {
        newBlob.FetchAttributes();
        if (newBlob.CopyState.Status != CopyStatus.Pending)
        {
            break;
        }
        //Sleep for a second may be
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
    blob.Delete();
```

Comment: There is no GetBlockReference in new api . New api provide GetBlobReferenceFromServer method. Without testing your code i can not understand that how your code get rid of http not found exception while copying to none exist blob.

Comment: Yes, there is: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.cloudblobcontainer.getblockblobreference.aspx. GetBlobReferenceFromServer is to be used when you don't know the type of the blob upfront and for that the blob needs to be present. Actually now that I have read your question more carefully, I have edited my answer (sorry about that, should have read your question more carefully in the 1st go).

Comment: Still newBlob.StartCopyFromBlob(blob.Uri) line throws http not found exception : (((

Comment: Can you post the complete code? Or try running the code I wrote. It worked for me from a console application.

Comment: OK It works and problem was not about code. But still i don't feel that while loop is neccessary. Thanks

Comment: The loop *is* necessary because if the file is large enough and you don't perform the wait, then you might delete it as it is still being copied to the destination.  @eMazeika suggests that you can use the CopyFromBlob() method, but that no longer exists in Azure.  Therefore, using the StartCopyFromBlob() method, and waiting for it to complete is the only method I've found that works. Gaurav Mantri - good job.

Answer (score 0):

The code in OP was almost fine except that an async copy method was called. The simplest code in new API should be:

```
var oldBlob = cloudBlobClient.GetBlobReferenceFromServer(oldBlobUri);
var newBlob = container.GetBlobReference("newblobname");
newBlog.CopyFromBlob(oldBlob);
oldBlob.Delete();
```